# Logging Spark Configuration Properties

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to log the properties for each Spark application that run in one Yarn cluster ( properties like spark.shuffle.compress, spark.reducer.maxMbInFlight, spark.executor.instances and so on ).

However i don't know if this information is logged anywhere. I know that we can access to the yarn logs through the "yarn" command but the properties I'm talking about are not store there.

Is there anyway to access to this kind of info?. The idea is to have a trace of all the applications that run in the cluster together with its properties to identify which ones have the most impact in their execution time.

Answer (score 0):

You could log it yourself... use `sc.getConf.toDebugString`, `sqlContext.getConf("")`  or `sqlContext.getAllConfs`.

```
scala> sqlContext.getConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
res129: String = 200

scala> sqlContext.getAllConfs
res130: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(hive.server2.thrift.http.cookie.is.httponly -> true, dfs.namenode.resource.check.interval ....

scala> sc.getConf.toDebugString
res132: String = 
spark.app.id=local-1449607289874
spark.app.name=Spark shell
spark.driver.host=10.5.10.153
```

**Edit**: However, I could not find the properties you specified among the 1200+ properties in sqlContext.getAllConfs :( Otherwise the documentation says:

> The application web UI at http://:4040 lists Spark properties
>   in the “Environment” tab. This is a useful place to check to make sure
>   that your properties have been set correctly. Note that only values
>   explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the
>   command line will appear. For all other configuration properties, you
>   can assume the default value is used.

Comment: I'm more interested in the properties of the sc context. As for the properties I'm talking about you can provide them either in the configuration file, when you are launching the application through spark-submit or through the context too. Thing is, I don't think they are logged anywhere and I'll probably have to figure out how to collect them.

Comment: Yes. Not all configs are in the SparkConf object, or any other conf object for that matter. For example, `spark.executor.instances` is not in SparkConf object. If you don't specify it as your option, it is not defined as a key in SparkConf. When it's used inside Spark source code, it's checked for existence and then given the default value such as [at this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L2186).